# Show IOS CABasicAnimation progress in label

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I would like to show the circular progress in the `label`. I have created a `UIView` subclass which shows the animation based on the input value. But I'm not able to show text in the `label`.

```
import UIKit
import GLKit

let ANGLE_START : CFloat  = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-90)
let ANGLE_END : CFloat = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(360)

struct Math {

    static func getPercentageFromDegrees(from angle: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return  (angle/360) * 100
    }

    public static func caliculateAngle(from input: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        // -90 for ANGLE_START is starting from -90, ew shoould remove from total angle so
        return  (2 * ((input-90)/360) * CGFloat.pi)
    }

    public static func shwoProgressFromInput(from input: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        // -90 for ANGLE_START is starting from -90, ew shoould remove from total angle so
        return  ((input)/100) * 360
    }

}

public final class AnimatedCircle: UIView {

        fileprivate var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fileprivate var tracklayer = CAShapeLayer()

        var label = UILabel()

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            createCircularPath()
            self.addLabel()
        }

        required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            createCircularPath()
            self.addLabel()
        }

        var progressColor:UIColor = UIColor.red {
            didSet {
                progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
            }
        }

        var trackColor:UIColor = UIColor.white {
            didSet {
                tracklayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
            }
        }

         func createCircularPath() {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2.0
            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0,
                                                             y: frame.size.height / 2.0),
                radius: (frame.size.width - 1.5)/2,
                startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * Double.pi),
                endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * Double.pi),
                clockwise: true)

            let progressPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0,
                                                               y: frame.size.height / 2.0),
                radius: (frame.size.width - 1.5)/2,
                startAngle: CGFloat( -0.5 * CGFloat.pi),
                endAngle: CGFloat(Math.caliculateAngle(from: Math.shwoProgressFromInput(from: 25))),
                clockwise: true)

                print("\n Percentage \(Math.getPercentageFromDegrees(from: 90) )")


            tracklayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
            tracklayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            tracklayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
            tracklayer.lineWidth = 5;
           // tracklayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
            layer.addSublayer(tracklayer)

            progressLayer.path = progressPath.cgPath
            progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
            progressLayer.lineWidth = 10.0;
            progressLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
            layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)

        }

        func setProgressWithAnimation(duration: TimeInterval, value: Float) {
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
            // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
            animation.fromValue = 0
            animation.toValue = 1
            animation.duration = duration
            animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            progressLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
            self.label.text = self.progressLayer.presentation()?.value(forKeyPath: "strokeEnd") as? String ?? "\(0) %"

        }

    func addLabel() {
        print("\n tracklayer.visibleRect \(String(describing: tracklayer.path?.boundingBox.offsetBy(dx: 100, dy: 100) ))")
        label = UILabel(frame: (tracklayer.path?.boundingBoxOfPath)!.insetBy(dx: 30, dy: 30))
        label.textColor = UIColor.red
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        label.text = "0 %"
        label.layer.contentsCenter = self.layer.contentsCenter
        self.addSubview(label)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)

    }
}
```

I have added the label to the circular view, I want to show the text value along with the animation progress. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is my image]

Comment: You can try Third Party Library called [MBCircularProgressBar](https://github.com/MatiBot/MBCircularProgressBar) which includes both animation of view with label in it

Comment: I would like to create my own animation, I have so many things to change along with that, So I will prefer own components.

Comment: Sure lable has correct frame ??  **tracklayer.path?.boundingBox** ??

Comment: where in code do you change text property with Canimation

Comment: that what I would like to know.

Comment: @EvilCoder you are not updating the label. When you start the animation it is obviously at 0%. You need to add a timer to your view controller to update your label periodically or create a custom label with an embedded timer on it so it can update itself.